# Alternative definition of suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Dan Freed's [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C/Notes/lecture9.pdf) eqn 9.53 (last page) there is an alternative definition of $n$th suspension

$$ \Sigma^n{X_+} = X \times S^n/X \times \{*\} \simeq X \times \mathbb{R}^n/X \times (\mathbb{R}^n\backslash B_r(0)) $$

Could somebody explain why this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equality just follows from $$\Sigma^n X_+ = \frac{X_+ \times S^n}{X_+ \vee S^n} \cong \frac{X \times S^n \sqcup \{*\} \times S^n}{X \times \{*\} \sqcup \{*\} \times S^n} \cong \frac{X \times S^n}{X \times *}.$$

The second follows from $\mathbb{R}^n/(\mathbb{R}^n - B_r(0)) \cong S^n$.

Comment: sorry but is it true that $\mathbb{R}^n/(\mathbb{R}^n - B_r(0)) \cong S^n$?  I thought that would be $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: For example, think of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then collapse everything outside the unit ball to a point. You still end up with something 2-dimensional, which turns out to be a sphere.

Comment: Got it!  I was confused by $\mathbb{R}^n - B_r(0) \cong S^{n-1}$